# htaccess redirect with domain masking not working when requesting root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Need help with achieving redirection + domain masking with .htaccess. It is partially working. It works for sub–pages and sub-directories but not the domain itself.

I have two domains "redir1" and "redir2".
The goal is to achieve redirection with .htaccess and masking like this:

```
http://redir2 —> http://redir1
http://redir2/sub.php —> http://redir1/sub.php
http://redir2/index.php —> http://redir1/index.php
```

And url displayed to visitor has to remain what they entered:

```
http://redir2
http://redir2/sub.php
http://redir2/index.php
```

But if they entered `http://redir1` they should see `http://redir1` in url.

each domain has two following files:
    index.php
    sub.php

Here is the code in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?redir2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://redir1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

It is working very well for all requests that have something after domain (sub-pages and sub-directories). For example:

```
http://redir2/sub.php
http://redir2/index.php
```

But if I type in just `http://redir2/` I get a "Not found" error:

```
The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.
```

Indeed I don't have index.html but I have index.php
How to solve the issue without adding index.html?

Thanks

Comment: `DirectoryIndex index.php` in redir2 htaccess file solved the problem. However a small note about Wordpress. If `redir1` is a Wordpress site it has it's own standard WP htaccess instructions. And it creates other problems. For example it may mask sub-pages ok. But it wouldn't mask the domain and just redirect to redir1 without masking.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to complete solve this problem on a wordpress site? I've tried what's suggested here but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with `DirectoryIndex index.php` ?