# htaccess redirect with domain masking for Wordpress site not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The below .htaccess configuration is not working on Wordpress site to achieve domain redirection with masking:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?redir2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://redir1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

This is .htaccess of `redir2` for redirecting to `redir1` with masking. The goal is to have user type in for example `redir2/sub`, served content of `redir1/sub`, but shown url of `redir2/sub`.

It is working fine on my local installation. But on my shared hosting it redirects without masking. I assume problem might be somewhere in server configuration.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Just for records here is another similar question I asked when I had problem with index file when redirecting with masking: [htaccess redirect with domain masking not working when requesting root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307198/htaccess-redirect-with-domain-masking-not-working-when-requesting-root-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress canonical URL functionality is designed to do this.

Although this plugin is not actively supported anymore, it just might work.

```
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: Disable Canonical URL Redirects
 Plugin URI: http://www.ImagineThought.com/
 Description: Disables the "Canonical URL Redirect" feature of WordPress (in versions of Wordpress 2.3 and greater). To use this plugin, simply activate it. Then, disable this if you need to re-enable the "Canonical URL Redirect" feature of WordPress.  
 Version: 1.0.11.0228
 Author: Geoffrey Griffith
 Author URI: http://www.ImagineThought.com/
 License: GPL
*/

 remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
 ?>
```