# htaccess url rewrite to wordpress page doesn't work for sub/child pages

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have a WordPress site at domain "wp-site.com". I have 2 pages on wp-site.com; their permalinks as follows:

- wp-site.com/ex-home1 ('home' page for "ex-domain1")
- wp-site.com/ex-home1/booking1 (child page of ex-home1)

The idea is to repeat this for a number of external domains, example "ex-domain1.com" and "ex-domain2.com", and 'point' to specific pages on wp-site.com such as ex-home2 & ex-home2/contact, etc. while keeping the external domain url in the browser. The reason for this being 1 central WP instance to manage a number of small, 2 to 3-page sites for divisions in the same group of companies.

On ex-domain1.com I have placed htaccess with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ex-domain1.com/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://wp-site.com/ex-home1/$1 [L,NE,P,QSA]
```

I have tried so many variations of this, which I found on SO and other forums, but the above code gets me the closest to what I want to achieve.

The issue I now have, is that the rewrite works perfectly for the 'home' page as well as the 'booking' page

```
wp-site.com/ex-home1 --> rewrites to --> ex-domain1.com
wp-site.com/ex-home1/booking1 --> rewrites to --> ex-domain1.com/booking
```

but the ex-domain1.com 'home' page is displayed again for the 'booking'/child page as well. As mentioned I have toyed extensively with the $ (end of string) and wildcard values to no avail. Most of the time I get a 404/'Page not found' error.

I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307198/htaccess-redirect-with-domain-masking-not-working-when-requesting-root-directory) that WordPress's own htaccess may cause issues. The wp-site.com WP htaccess is default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions of what I could try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK I added 'DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm' to htaccess. "Page not found" disappears, but now ex-domain1.com redirects to wp-site.com/ex-home1/ instead of rewriting. The /booking1 sub-page is rewritten correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a $1 but you aren't creating a capture group. Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ex-domain1.com/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wp-site.com/ex-home1/$1 [L,NE,P,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried your suggestion adding '(.*)$' capture group. I now receive a "Page not found" message, but is 'pointing' to the wp-site.com it seems (It is the WP generated not found page). Could there be an issue with the URL when it appends the $1 it has captured?